# Does $\mathbb E[\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\mid N=m]=\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb E[X_i]$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm always a bit confuse with this conditional expectation. Let $N$ a stopping time and $X_1,X_2,...$ random variables. Does $$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\ \Big|\  N=m\right]=\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb E[X_i] \ \ ?$$ 
the fact that $N$ is a random variable confuse me a bit on the interpretation of $\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ and the understanding of $\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\ \Big|\  N=m\right]$

Comment: is $N$ independent of every $X_i$ ?

Comment: @DominikKutek It's a stopping time for the sequence, so it can't be independent of the sequence (except non-random $N$)

Comment: Actually, if $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ is a filtration and $N$ is a non-negative, integer-valued, $\mathcal{F}_0$-measurable random variable independent of $\{X_i\}_{i\ge 1}$, then $N$ is a stopping time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathsf{P})$ is a probability space, $A\in\mathcal{F}$ with $\mathsf{P}(A)>0$, and $X$ is a r.v., then
$$
\mathsf{E}[X\mid A]=\frac{\mathsf{E}[X1_A]}{\mathsf{P}(A)}.
$$

Applying this to your case and assuming that $\mathsf{P}(N=m)>0$, one gets
$$
\mathsf{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\mid N=m\right]=\mathsf{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^m X_i 1\{N=m\}\right]/\mathsf{P}(N=m).
$$

If $N$ is independent of $\{X_i\}_{i\ge 1}$, then the RHS reduces to $\sum_{i=1}^m\mathsf{E}X_i$.

Comment: So, at the end, $$\frac{1}{\mathbb P(N=m)}\varepsilon E\left[\sum_{i=1}^m X_i1_{N=m}\right]=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(N=m)}\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbb E[X_i1_{N=m}]$$ $$=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(N=m)^2}\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbb E[X_i; \{N=m\}],$$ right ?

Comment: Check you 2nd line...

Comment: But at the end something is not clear : Does $\mathbb E[X_N\mid N=n]=\mathbb E[X_n\mid N=n]$ or not ? (because they always write that in my lecture).

Comment: That equality holds if $\mathsf{P}(N=n)>0$.

Comment: If $\mathbb P(N=n)=0$ what happen ? For example, take $X,Y$ continuous. Then, $\mathbb E[XY\mid X=x]=x\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x]$ or not ?

Comment: If $\mathsf{P}(N=n)=0$, then the conditional expectation is not defined. If $X$ is continuous, $\mathsf{E}[XY\mid X=x]$ is the notation for a function $m(x)$ s.t. $m(X(\omega))=\mathsf{E}[XY\mid \sigma(X)](\omega)$.

Comment: Sorry, last question : so if $X$ is continuous $\mathbb E[XY\mid X=x]=x\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x]$ is not correct ? Because, I know that $\mathbb E[XY\mid X]=X\mathbb E[Y\mid X]$ hold. So I could imagine that $\mathbb E[XY\mid X=x]=x\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x]$ hold.

Comment: Well, to use your notation,  $\mathbb E[XY\mid \sigma (X)]=X\mathbb E[Y\mid X]$ and thus, if $x=X(\omega )$, then $m(x)=x\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x]$ should hold, no ?

Comment: Also, in my lecture, they say that if $\mathbb P\{X=x\}=0$ (and $X$ discrete), then $\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x]=0$ and if $f_X(x)=0$ (for $X$ continuous), then $\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x]=0$. Does it make sense for you ? (because you said is not defined, whereas in my lecture, they define it).

Comment: 1. Conditional expectations w.r.t. events are defined only for events having positive probability. Setting $E[Y\mid X=x]=0$ for $x$ with $\mathsf{P}(X=x)=0$ (discrete case) is a matter of convinience.

2. For a measurable function $f$ s.t. $\mathsf{E}|f(X,Y)|<\infty$, $\mathsf{E}[f(X,Y)\mid X=x]=\mathsf{E}[f(x,Y)\mid X=x]$.